# How to set iptables rules that won't get pushed down the list

Tags: networking, vpn, iptables, openvpn, wireguard

I am trying to setup iptables rules that will allow OpenVPN and Wireguard traffic on two servers. One of the servers also runs Yunohost and the other one, Cloudron.

The problem is that my defined rules for VPN traffic get pushed down the iptables list by Yunohost & Cloudron on system restart and as a result, VPN traffic gets rejected down the pipe before even reaching the rules that let them thru.

I tried setting up systemd services which were supposed to wait a few minutes and then prepend the VPN rules to the tops of the relevant chains -which is also desirable for performance purposes since the servers are meant primarily to run VPN services; Cloudron and Yunohost are only there to provide secondary services such as a wiki, a file server, etc.- but I'm obviously doing it wrong because when I try to delay the script with a sleep command on top, the whole system hangs at startup until that command finishes. Not cool.

I don't want to mess with Cloudron's own firewall script because I am not sure if it will get overwritten in the future by some update or whatever. I don't want to use persistent rules for the same reason because Cloudron dynamically manages the tables as I add/remove features to it. I just want to add some rules to the top when and if the server ever restarts.

What would be a proper way to define some rules that would go on top of the iptables rules list and stay there no matter what?

I also wonder if my rules look OK. Here's the script I use:

```
#!/bin/sh

#### Create iptables rules to let VPN traffic ##
## OpenVPN ##
iptables -I INPUT 1 -i tun0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT 1 -i eth0 -p udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -i eth0 -o tun0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -i tun0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING 1 -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

## Wireguard ##
iptables -I INPUT 1 -i wg0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT 1 -i eth0 -p udp --dport 51820 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -i wg0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD 1 -i eth0 -o wg0 -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING 1 -s 10.9.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: The problem is if any scripts keep adding rules to the top of the list they can't be 'stopped' from doing that - any other function that does this as well such as other firewall scripts, etc. can still insert at the beginning and push your rules down.  There's no way to *lock* rules at the top.

Comment: Then maybe I should schedule the script so that it runs at certain intervals. I never set up a cron job before. I'll start looking into how to setup one.

Comment: This crontab entry looks promising: @reboot sleep 180 && sh /home/scripts/vpnfirewall.sh